# Microsoft Speech Recognition - numbers only

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar

Is there a way to limit the grammar to numbers only in either dictation mode or in constructing a custom grammar XML file? Obviously I can't enter all the numbers into the XML, but there has to be an easy way.

Comment: Why not only add 0~9 into the XML file, and recognize a single number each time?

Comment: So if the User says ninety-one, how would that work?

Comment: Just make a rule that the user should say `nine one` instead of `ninety-one`. Otherwise you should add `ten,twenty,...,ninety,...` to your grammar XML file. That may influence your recognition ratio as the number of grammar increase too much.

Comment: Thanks! Frankly, I thought there would be a simpler solution...Also, what if the number is two hundred thousand and one point 35...I know I can build it into the XML but that is not really an "easy way"...

Comment: I was hoping for some ways using semantics in the XML file or something like myGrammar.DictationLoad "numbersonly", SLOStatic where the numbers only is some subset of the default dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but I have a solution in case you still need it.  Here is the file I came up with.  This requires the user to speak single digits only, such as one five seven (not one fifty-seven, which will not work).  You can play around with this to suit your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US" root="rootRule" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">
  <rule id="rootRule">
    <item repeat="1-">
      <ruleref uri="#digit"></ruleref>
    </item>
  </rule>
  <rule id="digit">
    <one-of>
      <item>0</item>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>3</item>
      <item>4</item>
      <item>5</item>
      <item>6</item>
      <item>7</item>
      <item>8</item>
      <item>9</item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```